# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} y^2 \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dydx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} y^2 \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dydx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[x,1]}(y) y^2 \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dydx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[x,1]}(y) y^2 \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dxdy$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[0,y]}(x) y^2 \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dxdy$$

so I am stuck here and I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first integration with respect to $x$ is clearly easier. I suggest you to apply Fubini theorem and reverse the order of integrals.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} y^2 \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dydx = \int_{0}^{1} y^2\left( \int_{0}^{y} \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y})dx \right)dy.$$ And $$\int_{0}^{y} \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{y}) dx = \frac{y}{2\pi} [-\cos(2\pi \frac{x}{y})]_0^y = 0$$

Comment: why did you take $y^2$ common out in first integration? have you changed the order?